# How to send item in list as '1' and not ' ['1'] '

Tags: python, discord.py, message

I want to send message as '1' and not ' ['1'] '. Here's The Code:

```
@client.command()
async def add(message, *args):
    numz = ""
    for arg in args:
        numz = numz + "" + arg
    numz = numz.split()
    num = [item[0] for item in numz]
    num1 = [item[1]for item in numz]
    numm = num + num1
    zembed = discord.Embed(
        title="Here's The Answer: ", 
        description=str(num) + '+' + str(num1) + ' = ' + str(numm),
        url="",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
        )
    await message.send(embed=zembed)
```

Here's the embed message:
`['4']+['5'] = ['4', '5']`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `add` is

```
@client.command()
async def add(message, *args):
    answer = add_args(args)

    zembed = discord.Embed(
        title="Here's The Answer: ", 
        description=answer,
        url="",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    await message.send(embed=zembed)
```

and your code is supposed to

- sum the arguments as numbers, you can do

```
def add_args(*args):
    # Join the arguments using ' + ' as separator ('4 + 5 + 6')
    l_arg = ' + '.join(args)

    # Map the arguments to integers and sum them (4 + 5 + 6 = 15)
    r_arg = sum(map(int, args))

    return f"{l_arg} = {r_arg}"

print(add_args('4', '5'))  # Outputs 4 + 5 = 9
```

- join the arguments as strings, you can do

```
def add_args(*args):
    # Join the arguments using ' + ' as separator ('4 + 5 + 6')
    l_arg = ' + '.join(args)

    # Join the arguments using '' as separator ('456')
    r_arg = ''.join(args)

    return f"{l_arg} = {r_arg}"

print(add_args('4', '5'))  # Outputs 4 + 5 = 45
```